# Rails API accept post with two type of payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. I have a single endpoint and I have to process two type of payload. Any idea on how can I implement this? Thank you.

Payload 1

```json
{
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
}
```

Payload 2

```json
{
    "guest_fname": "John",
    "guest_lname": "Doe",
}
```

Comment: Allowing different attribute names when posting forms leads to all kinds of issues. You can add custom setters and getters and transform the input, but then you will still miss advanced features like validation messages that aren't linked to the correct form fields. IMO you would need a very good reason to fight against Ruby on Rails' naming conventions. Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Change params before create new record if you really need to do it.

```rb
  params["fname"] = params["fname"] || params["guest_fname"]
  params["lname"] = params["lname"] || params["guest_lname"]
```

And read about `to_unsafe_h`

UPDATE:

```
# controller
before_action :alter_params, only: %i[create update]

def create
end
def update
end

private
  def alter_params
    params["fname"] = params["fname"] || params["guest_fname"]
    params["lname"] = params["lname"] || params["guest_lname"]
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:lname, :fname, :guest_lname, :guest_fname, ...)
  end
```

it works. But no idea that it's the best solition.

UPDATE #2:

```
# controller
def create
end
def update
end

private

  def user_params
    params["fname"] = params["fname"] || params["guest_fname"]
    params["lname"] = params["lname"] || params["guest_lname"]
    params.require(:user).permit(:lname, :fname, :guest_lname, :guest_fname, ...)
  end
```

Comment: Thank you but how should the params.require and .permit looks like?

Comment: Update it.
to_unsafe_h was not needed.

Comment: I got an error " param is missing or the value is empty". I tested it and it returns null if it is set to "guest_fname".